# 'ENOENT: No such file or directory' Error in Docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, terminal

I was trying to run the following code in the terminal:

```sh
docker build -t node-docker-project .
```

My '**Dockerfile**' is as follows:

```
FROM node:16-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I tried severally, but the error that is brought out continuously is as shown below:

```sh
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I thought that I had not installed dependencies but I have checked that out and it is all well in my local app directory. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

The problem of the code above is as indicated in the error message. It states that it can't find the file in the specified directory:

```sh
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
```

Look at the '**Dockerfile**', you will see that you have used `./app` in the following:

```
COPY package.json ./app
```

instead of `/app` (Remove the . ) because it tries to navigate into an unsearchable folder and file. Run it and now it shall give you a success message.

Comment: I'd recommend using `.` as the `COPY` destination.  That will copy into the current `WORKDIR` and you won't have to repeat its absolute path.